# jQuery - Put a custom directory in front of all anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to put a custom folder name in front of all links on the page, using jQuery?

Example, if I have these links on my website:

```
<a href="/user/login">Login</a>
<a href="/user/register">Register</a>
<a href="/user/forum">Forum</a>
```

Would it be possible to do, so when the page loads, they will automatically convert to:

```
<a href="/foldername/user/login">Login</a>
<a href="/foldername/user/register">Register</a>
<a href="/foldername/user/forum">Forum</a>
```

The change is that `/foldername` has been added to all the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href','/foldername'+$(this).attr('href'));
});
```

or

```
$('a').attr('href', function(_, href) {
 return '/foldername'+href;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
$("a[href^='/']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", "/foldername" + $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QKVAm/

The idea is very simple, just iterate through each anchors, and append the foldername to each href.

`var $this = $(this);` is for selector caching so that jQuery will not select the element from DOM twice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could walk the DOM tree and parse all `<a>` tags and change their `href` based on whether they match a regexp.

Here it is in pure javascript:

```
var matcher = new RegExp("/^[/a-z]*$/");

var filter = { 
    acceptNode: function(node){ 
        if(node.tagName === "a"){ 
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; 
        }
    }
}

var tree_walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, filter, false);

while(tree_walker.nextNode()){
    var a_elem = tree_walker.currentNode;
    var loc = a_elem.getAttribute("href");
    if ( matcher.test(loc) ){
        a_elem.setAttribute("href", "/foldername" + loc);
    }
}
```

`document.TreeWalker` is a DOM builtin: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.createTreeWalker)

and the regexp should parse typical folder strings. I don't know how jQuery handles this kind of stuff but this is pretty efficient since `TreeWalker` is native and well designed to return pretty much only what you need.